# Grunt Watch no running task for JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am not sure why my grunt-watch is not running for the JS or CSS configurations

My Grunt file is in a 'tools' folder.  The project folder structure looks like this:

```
-index.html
-js
-css
-tools
--package.json
--node modules
--gruntfile.js
```

Here is my CSS folder structure:

```
-css
--src
---styles.css
---third-party
----bootstrap.css
```

Here is my JS folder structure:

```
-js
--src
---app.js
---third-party
----jquery.js
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "matchdep": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my gruntfile, it is the watch task that does not seem to work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

  //Loads the necessary tasks for this Grunt file.
  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-contrib-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  // Project configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Load package.json file so that access is given to the project name and version number.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Constants for the Gruntfile so we can easily change the path for our environments.
    //note: end with /
    BASE_PATH: '../',
    JS_SOURCE_PATH:     '../js/src/',
    JS_BUILD_PATH:      '../js/build/',
    CSS_SOURCE_PATH:    '../css/src/',
    CSS_BUILD_PATH:     '../css/build/',

    uglify: {
        files: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: '<%= JS_BUILD_PATH %>',
            flatten: false,
        }
    },

    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>.jshintrc',
            force: true
        },
        all: [
                '<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>**/*.js',
                '!<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>third-party/**/*.js'
            ]
    },

    cssmin: {
        options: {
            keepBreaks: true,
            report: 'gzip'
        },
        minify: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= CSS_SOURCE_PATH %>',
            src: '**/*.css',
            dest: '<%= CSS_BUILD_PATH %>'
        }
    },

    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            nospawn: true
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint']
        },
        css: {
            files: ['<%= CSS_SOURCE_PATH %>**/*.css'],
            tasks: ['cssmin']
        },
        html: {
            files: ['<%= BASE_PATH %>*.html']
        }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

  grunt.registerTask('doit', ['uglify', 'cssmin']);

  grunt.registerTask('css', ['cssmin']);

  grunt.registerTask('hint', ['jshint']);

};
```

Edit:  Here is the output when I run 'grunt watch --verbose'

```
Running tasks: watch

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.css.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.html.files exists in config...OK
Live reload server started on port: 35729
Watching ../js/src/app.js for changes.
Watching ../js/src/third-party for changes.
Watching ../js/src/third-party/jquery.js for changes.
Watching ../css/src/styles.css for changes.
Watching ../css/src/third-party for changes.
Watching ../css/src/third-party/bootstrap.css for changes.
Watching ../index.html for changes.
Watching ../css for changes.
Watching ../js for changes.
Watching  for changes.
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? some errors? doesn't compile?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri It is not running the tasks.  For instance when I save "app.js" the jshint task is not run.  Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Where's your gruntfile? In what folder?

Comment: @MarioAraque I updated the question.  My grunt file is in a folder called 'tools' along with the package.json.

Comment: Did you try to type "grunt watch"? Because you don't have any register task related with watch plugin. The gruntfile is located in the correct place.

Comment: Yes, I have 'grunt watch' running with the livereload plugin.

Comment: Okey. Another question, is necessary the "!" in this line? '!<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>third-party/**/*.js'

Comment: What is the output when you run with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: @MarioAraque I'll remove that.  The line ''!<%= JS_SOURCE_PATH %>third-party/**/*.js' is so that jshint does not run on those files.  I don't really want to lint jquery :)

Comment: @steveax I editted the question by adding the information of the output that I get when I run 'grunt watch --verbose'

Comment: But the console does show something if you save app.js file?

Comment: @MarioAraque No the console doesn't show that anything was run when I save app.js :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is path and the position of gruntfile.

You have this:

```
    BASE_PATH: '../',
    JS_SOURCE_PATH:     '../js/src/',
    JS_BUILD_PATH:      '../js/build/',
    CSS_SOURCE_PATH:    '../css/src/',
    CSS_BUILD_PATH:     '../css/build/',
```

Seems that gruntfile isn't in the root directory but in a folder.

Gruntfile (and package.json, node_modules) need to be in the root of the project to work well.

If you would like to change its pat you can set two parameters `--base` and `--gruntfile`

Try to move gruntfile into the root of your project and change path like this:

```
    BASE_PATH: '',
    JS_SOURCE_PATH:     'js/src/',
    JS_BUILD_PATH:      'js/build/',
    CSS_SOURCE_PATH:    'css/src/',
    CSS_BUILD_PATH:     'css/build/',
```

After launch from your console:

```
grunt watch
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue.  All of the tasks work when I run them individually.  Like 'grunt css', and 'grunt hint' for example.  It is only the watch tasks that are not working which I thought should run when I save a file that is 'watched'.

Comment: +1 with Mdd, the Gruntfile, in his case, is in the correct place.

Comment: try to remove options from gruntfile to test if it works @Mdd

Comment: I did remove the options but it did not work.  One thing I noticed, when I have grunt watch running, and save my 'index.html' file the page refreshes.  

It is just the CSS files, and the JS files that are not running their tasks upon Save, and are not refreshing the browser.

Comment: Maybe this is an error, because you dont have any tasks related with "html" watch task.

Comment: try to remove html tasks to understand if is the problem @Mdd

Comment: Removing the html task did not change anything sadly.  I am testing by firing up grunt watch, and saving the 'app.js' file to see if jshint runs.

Comment: I'm not sure what it was, but moving the gruntfile and package.json worked.  I must have a syntax error somewhere because keeping them in the 'tools' folder has worked in the past.  Thanks everyone for the assistance!